# R plot all columns as violin side by side

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I havea dataframe, with 12 column and 270 rows, I read from a .csv file and I want to "compare" them - plotting them within one plot.

```
h1  h2  h3  h4  h5  h6 ...
1   5   2   1   0   0
1   1   0   0   2   3
2   11  4   3   1   1
3   3   1   1   3   6 
...
```

I want to get 14 violin charts side by side (or the first 6 and other 6 in a different plot), but I am unsure how.

I know it should go something like this:

`ggplot(df , aes(x = value, y= variable)) + geom_violin(aes(fill = variable)) + theme(legend.position="bottom")`
But I only get 'object variable not found'

Edit:

Apparently the code I reference is wrong (I wrote it, but don't remember how and what df actually is composed of) - so how can I achieve this?

[image]

Comment: Your code assumes there are variables in your dataframe called `value` and `variable`. Is it the case? You only show variables called `h1`, `h2` etc.

Comment: No, he is referencing the defaults from gather() or pivot_longer() that change the date to long format with only 2 columns: variable storing names and value storing values. Otherwise his plot should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to first `pivot_longer` your data frame. Since you do not have any reproducible data, let us first make some:

```r
set.seed(69)
df        <- data.frame(replicate(14, rnorm(270, runif(1, 5, 10))))
names(df) <- paste0("h", 1:14)
```

Now we can do:

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr)

plot_df      <- pivot_longer(df, cols = 1:14)
plot_df$name <- factor(plot_df$name, paste0("h", 1:14))

ggplot(plot_df, aes(name, value, fill = name)) + geom_violin()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2020-07-28 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: thank you for you answer it works nice, just what i have been looking for

Answer (score 1):

I hope I understood what you want. Try this, but be careful that all your variables are numeric.

```
library(tidyverse)
    
df %>%
  gather(key = "variable", value = "value") %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = variable, y = value)) + 
    geom_violin(aes(fill = variable)) + 
    theme(legend.position = "bottom") + 
    guides(fill = guide_legend(reverse = TRUE)) +
    coord_flip() +
    xlab("") + ylab("")
```